# Magento 2: what is the search_engine.xml? How to declare a new search engine?

Tags: magento2, configuration, xml, search, catalogsearch

Some of you may have noticed the presence of the following file `app/code/Magento/Search/etc/search_engine.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<engines xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Search/etc/search_engine.xsd">
    <engine name="mysql">
        <feature name="synonyms" support="true" />
    </engine>
</engines>
```

My assumption is that this file is somehow declaring the search engine to be used (mysql here).

So here are my questions:

- **How is that file exactly being used in Magento 2?**
- **Can one declare a different search engine by creating a `search_engine.xml` file? If so, is there anything else to declare a new search engine?**
- **Is it somehow related to the [`search_request.xml` file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114895/magento-2-what-is-the-search-request-xml-file-used-for?rq=1)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is that file exactly being used in Magento 2?

If I trace back the usage of the `engines` configuration in this file, I end up in `Magento\Search\Model\SearchEngine\Config`. Its interface is

```
interface ConfigInterface
{
    /**
     * Search engine feature: synonyms
     */
    const SEARCH_ENGINE_FEATURE_SYNONYMS = 'synonyms';

    /**
     * Get declared features of a search engine
     *
     * @param string $searchEngine
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getDeclaredFeatures($searchEngine);

    /**
     * Checks if a particular search feature is supported
     *
     * @param string $featureName
     * @param string $searchEngine
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isFeatureSupported($featureName, $searchEngine);
}
```

So this configuration is obviously meant to declare supported features for different search engines (MySQL, ElasticSearch, ...), currently only "synonyms".

As of Magento CE 2.1 this is used in

- `Magento\Search\Model\SearchEngine\MenuBuilder` - a plugin that removes the "Search Terms" entry in the backend if the current search engine does not support synonyms
- `Magento\Search\Controller\Adminhtml\Synonyms\ResultPageBuilder` - if you go to the search terms page anyways, you will see a notice

---

> Can one declare a different search engine by creating a search_engine.xml file? If so, is there anything else to declare a new search engine?

No, you only define the supported features here. The engine is defined via `di.xml`. This is how the Search module adds the "mysql" engine to the selectable engines in the **configuration**:

```
<type name="Magento\Search\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Engine">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="engines" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mysql" xsi:type="string">MySQL</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Here it adds the MySQL adapter **for searching**:

```
<type name="Magento\Search\Model\AdapterFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="adapters" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mysql" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Adapter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

And this how the CatalogSearch module defines the engine implementation **for indexing**:

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\EngineProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="engines" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mysql" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Engine</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

There are a few more classes of the CatalogSearchModule that are different based on the selected engine:

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandlerFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configPath" xsi:type="const">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\EngineInterface::CONFIG_ENGINE_PATH</argument>
        <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mysql" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandler</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

...

<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexStructureFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configPath" xsi:type="const">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\EngineInterface::CONFIG_ENGINE_PATH</argument>
        <argument name="structures" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mysql" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexStructure</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

...

<type name="Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\IntervalFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configPath" xsi:type="const">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\EngineInterface::CONFIG_ENGINE_PATH</argument>
        <argument name="intervals" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mysql" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\Interval</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="scope" xsi:type="const">Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

...

<type name="Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\DataProviderFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configPath" xsi:type="const">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\EngineInterface::CONFIG_ENGINE_PATH</argument>
        <argument name="dataProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mysql" xsi:type="string">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Dynamic\DataProvider</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="scope" xsi:type="const">Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

You will notice that in `di.xml`, factories are configured and the "engine" configuration is passed indirectly as `$configPath` argument. If you adhere to the standard fulltext search indexer which uses these factories, you will need to add implementations of all these interfaces for your engine.

---

> Is it somehow related to the search_request.xml file?

It's both related to the search, so "somehow", yes. But `search_request.xml` is independent of the engine if I understand it right.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the file and I could only find it in the release candidates of Magento 2.1.0 (and thus in the develop branch). It is not present in earlier versions.

It was [announced](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1_RC1EE.html) that Magento 2.1.0 would include Elasticsearch. I assume, looking at the structure of the XML, that the Elasticsearch module will also include a `search_engine.xml` exposing `<engine name="elasticsearch">` to the system as an engine. I could not yet find anything like that in the release candidates. Also I could not find a file like this in the Magento Solr module. Also I could not find the XSD file `search_engine.xsd`.

If I look in the Magento Admin, I can configure the Catalog Search engine and choose between MySQL and Solr, but this is coming from a DI configuration and not from the `search_engine.xml`.

Probably Magento is rewriting this part with the introduction of Elasticsearch. I would think that this is really work in progress or not yet made publicly available, except for this one file, maybe accidentally?

Comment: Yeah that was my assumption too, I ended up assuming it was WIP. I'll leave the question open for some time as 2.1 is gonna be out this week, maybe some people will be able to enlight us